# KEX error - "kex protocol error: type 30 seq 1" after windows 11 update

Tags: ssh, git, putty, bitbucket.org

Local machine has a bitbucket repository cloned using SSH. After windows 11 update, git push/pull etc cause the error "**kex protocol error: type 30 seq 1**". I can't find a working solution after hours of debugging.

**What I did**

- Updated the git scm
- Updated putty
- Changed the Git bash ssh client to putty
- Changed the order of diffie-hellman key exchange priority in putty
- Added diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 to sshd_config file/Added the
- Tried with putty, powershell, visual studio code etc
- Generated new ssh keys and added them to ssh agent

Nothing seems to work. Is there anything that I am missing or anything can be done? Kindly help

**Update - Content of my sshd_config file**

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

**Debug Log**

```
OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [2406:da00:ff00::3403:4be7] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mev/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/me/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
kex protocol error: type 30 seq 1
debug1: Received SSH2_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED for 1
```

**Solution**

After so many things, OS update and software changes, **the issue is related to IP address of the network.**
Everything works as expected in IPv4. the mentioned error happens on IPv6 networks only. It might be something related to bitbucket implementation of their SSH key exchange. Hope this will help somebody

Comment: If you've tried with PuTTY and got a similar error, can you include the whole log messages from PuTTY as well?

Comment: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 is an old method, sometimes not supported. If in sshd_config you have "D-H group exchange", set to preferred "D-H group 14" before it.

Comment: @user1686 will try to extract the log

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1731001/edit) your post with new information, rather than using comments.

Comment: Where does `tracert 2406:da00:ff00::3403:4be7` lead? Also, this is just the OpenSSH log – do you have a PuTTY log as well?

Comment: Although the address is correct, the rest of the output looks like you're reaching a different server than intended (the 'banner' is wrong for BitBucket, and it's selecting a key-exchange algorithm that BitBucket does not offer)...whatever you ended up reaching, it's claiming that it supports "curve25519-sha256" when it actually does not.

Comment: @user1686 I downgraded and reset my PC in desperation. I will give more details as soon as everything is back online again. Than you so much